# Split lines according to specific patterns

Tags: split, line

I have a text like below:

```
HWI-ST150_0129:2:8:19270:131483#0 chr1 735440 819383 HWI-ST150_0129:5:44:4612:112201#0 chr1 735446 819377 HWI-ST150_0129:5:61:12668:134666#0 chr1 735444 819380 

HWI-ST150_0129:2:27:6777:92418#0 chr10 107950655 107951635 HWI-ST150_0129:3:61:5129:81938#0 chr10 107950674 107951702

......
```

So we can see each line contains the pattern like "HWI-ST150_0129:2:8:19270:131483#0 chr1 735440 819383"
I hope to make it into:

```
HWI-ST150_0129:2:8:19270:131483#0 chr1 735440 819383
HWI-ST150_0129:5:44:4612:112201#0 chr1 735446 819377
HWI-ST150_0129:5:61:12668:134666#0 chr1 735444 819380
HWI-ST150_0129:2:27:6777:92418#0 chr10 107950655 107951635
HWI-ST150_0129:3:61:5129:81938#0 chr10 107950674 107951702
```

How can I do it? Both bash and python ok.
I personally like bash more
thx

Answer (score 0):

What language or code are you working in?

Find the index of each HWI in the string.
The insert right before the HWI "\r" or maybe "\r\n" basically inserting a retun char and newline.

May want to look into REGEX as well.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify a tool or language...

**Tool (Windows)**: use Notepad++ and use the following regex for replacing:

Search:

```
(HWI-\w+:\d+:\d+:\d+:\d+#\d+ \w+ \d+ \d+)
```

Replace with:

```
\1\n
```

**Language (any OS)**: use Perl and the given regexes. The replace regex should be:

```
$1\n
```

Answer (score 0):

**This will give you the exact result**

```
 <?php
    $text ="HWI-ST150_0129:2:8:19270:131483#0 chr1 735440 819383 HWI-ST150_0129:5:44:4612:112201#0 chr1 735446 819377 HWI-ST150_0129:5:61:12668:134666#0 chr1 735444 819380 HWI-ST150_0129:2:27:6777:92418#0 chr10 107950655 107951635 HWI-ST150_0129:3:61:5129:81938#0 chr10 107950674 107951702";
    $arrHw = explode('HWI',$text);

    for($i=1;$i<count($arrHw);$i++):
        echo "HWI".$arrHw[$i]."<br/>";
    endfor;
    ?>
```